# Port forwarding via remote hostname unable to connect, works via IP

Tags: networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel, internal-dns

I'm trying to perform local port forwarding over ssh to a remote server (the "jump server") which has access to a mariadb server (the "DB server"). The jump server has the public IP address 1.2.3.4, while the DB server has the internal IP address 10.5.6.7. The following command works as expected:

```
ssh -v -N user@1.2.3.4 -L 3306:10.5.6.7:3306
```

However, the DB server's internal IP address is not static, so I'd like to rely on its internal hostname, mariadb.local. However the following does *not* work:

```
ssh -v -N user@1.2.3.4 -L 3306:mariadb.local:3306
```

Producing the following output from sshd on the jump server:

```
debug1: active: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug1: server_init_dispatch
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype direct-tcpip rchan 2 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: server_request_direct_tcpip: originator 127.0.0.1 port 58953, target mariadb.local port 3306
connect_to mariadb.local: unknown host (Try again)
debug1: server_input_channel_open: failure direct-tcpip
```

So it seems like it must be a DNS resolution issue, but I'm not sure how DNS resolution works during port forwarding so this is where my knowledge breaks down. To be clear, this is the result of ping from the jump server:

```
/ # ping mariadb.local
PING mariadb.local (10.5.6.7): 56 data bytes
```

---

A note: This whole environment is actually within kubernetes, so the hostname mariadb.local is being made available via as service, and resolved through k8s coreDNS. However, I can't see why that would affect anything, so I omitted it from the main description of the problem to avoid complicating the matter further, and avoid suggestions of "use kubectl port-forward"; this isn't an option as I want to make this service available to users I don't want to give kubectl access to.

Comment: Hm, I see in the source that it does `getaddrinfo()` on that destination. I wonder if the unknown host error is somewhat related to the sshd beeing isolated, so it cannot access nscd or hosts file. Could you try to run a sshd in foreground with debug on a different port and no fork to see if this helps? And maybe even strace it?

Comment: Didn't manage to get sshd running in foreground (not sure how to do that) but I compiled a test program using `getaddrinfo()` and that works fine, so it must be to do specifically with how sshd is running... am still investigating

Comment: So I tracked down where things go wrong, it's right where the separate process is created for sshd, for privilege separation. This is now quite a way out of my area of knowledge, but I'm hoping that can help someone work out what's causing this. basically `getaddrinfo()` is not able to resolve the internal IPs while in a less privileged state.

Comment: Great work. I am not sure if I just guessed right or if I heard of that before. Did you run the server with `-d`? I would try `UsePrivilegeSeparation off` and also try to delete `/var/run/nscd/socket`.

Comment: `UsePrivilegeSeparation off` is no longer possible as they removed that option, but it's okay, I dug deeper and found the issue (see my answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that the user was chrooted, which as it turns out, if `UsePrivilegeSeparation` is on (which is mandatory as of openSSH 7.5) will also chroot the forked process.

Tangibly, what this resulted in was the process not being able to read `/etc/resolv.conf` which is necessary to resolve hostnames correctly. There are a few [solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469209/how-to-resolve-hostnames-in-chroot) to this, but essentially if you're having issues like this it's likely that `resolv.conf` is not readable for some reason or another (another possible issue would be permissions of that file).

Comment: For OpenSSH_7.4p1, I also had to copy `libnss_files.so.2` (I only work with the hosts file) into the chroot. In other use cases it might also be necessary to copy `libnss_compat.so.2` and/or `libnss_dns.so.2`. With an older version, this was not necessary